# Node js Error: Unable to load shared library

Tags: node.js, osx-snow-leopard

I'm trying to require any NodeJs addon that used "node-waf configure build" when installed with no luck. I keep getting the same message:

```
Error: Unable to load shared library /Users/xxxx/node_modules/pdfkit/node_modules/flate/lib/zlib_bindings.node

Error: Unable to load shared library /Users/xxxx/node_modules/rsa/rsaBinding.node

Error: Unable to load shared library /Users/xxxx/node_modules/dcrypt/build/default/dcrypt.node
```

addons I tried:
pdfkit, rsa, dcrypt

I'm on MacOsx 10.6.8, nodejs v0.6.5, npm .1.0-alpha-6

Answer (score 2):

I encountered same problem with bcrypt and found it's because my node was 32bit and bcrypt was build as 64bit. After I build a 64bit node, all things work fine now.

Answer (score 1):

PDFKit now uses the builtin `zlib` module from Node instead of the old `flate` dependency.